# How to calculate the distance in Voronoi Diagram?

Tags: intuition, voronoi-diagram

As per my Understanding:

**Voronoi diagram:** A Voronoi diagram is based on the minimum distance needed to reach a landmark. If you need to go to a metro station, the most natural algorithm is going to the nearest one.

I know there are python [packages](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) and code to calculate Voronoi. But I'm finding it hard to understand the concept of **Voronoi diagram**, **tessellations**, and calculating the **minimum distance**.

Can someone explain the intuition of the Voronoi diagram?

Comment: Can you please give a bit more context to your first question: do you already have a tessellation and want to calculate distances based on that structure? or do you want to build one where input points are geolocations?

Comment: Python's `scipy` does offer a solution to this problem: a [tessellation on a sphere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi.html#scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi), the api is fairly similar to the one in the example in your post, you just need to supply the radius of the sphere, in this case the radius of Earth

Comment: Is there something in particular at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram that you don't understand?